# how to block someone from placing in the same spot TIC TAC TOE

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to learn how to block someone from placing an X or an O on the spots where has already been played. how do I make so when picture X is displayed, picture O cannot be placed in the same spot as the X? What i've done so far is the Nombreup and Nombre are the keybinds that you can use to place either X or O. I just do not know how to prevent it to place an O or X on a spot where an O or X has been placed (prevent cheating during a tic tac toe game).
Here is my code :

```
document.onkeydown = Nombre;
Nombreup1 = 49; Nombreup2 = 50; Nombreup3 = 51;
Nombreup4   = 52; Nombreup5 = 53; Nombreup6 = 54;
Nombreup7   = 55; Nombreup8 = 56; Nombreup9 = 57;
Nombre7 = 103; Nombre8 = 104; Nombre9 = 105;
Nombre4 = 100; Nombre5 = 101; Nombre6 = 102;
Nombre3 = 99; Nombre2 = 98; Nombre1 = 97;

function Nombre(e){
  toucheCourante = e.keyCode;

  if (toucheCourante == Nombre7){
  lettreO7();

  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre8){
    lettreO8();

  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre9){
    lettreO9();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre6){
    lettreO6();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre5){
    lettreO5();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre4){
    lettreO4();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre3){
    lettreO3();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre2){
    lettreO2();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombre1){
    lettreO1();
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////

    if (toucheCourante == Nombreup7){
    lettreX7();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup8){
      lettreX8();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup9){
      lettreX9();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup6){
      lettreX6();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup5){
      lettreX5();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup4){
      lettreX4();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup3){
      lettreX3();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup2){
      lettreX2();


  } else if (toucheCourante == Nombreup1){
      lettreX1();
      }

}

function casearret(){
 if (c1 < cup1) {

 }
}





function lettreO1()
{
  lettreO = new Image();
  lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
  lettreO.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreO, 40, 265,95,93);

  }
}

function lettreX1()
{
  lettreX = new Image();
  lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
  lettreX.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreX, 40, 265,95,93);

  }
}

function lettreO2()
{
  lettreO = new Image();
  lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
  lettreO.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreO, 145, 265,110,93);

  }
}

function lettreX2()
{
  lettreX = new Image();
  lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
  lettreX.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreX, 145, 265,110,93);

  }
}

function lettreO3()
{
  lettreO = new Image();
  lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
  lettreO.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreO, 265, 265,95,93);
  }
}

function lettreX3()
{
  lettreX = new Image();
  lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
  lettreX.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreX, 265, 265,95,93);
  }
}

function lettreO4()
{
  lettreO = new Image();
  lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
  lettreO.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreO, 40,149,95,107);

  }
}

function lettreX4()
{
  lettreX = new Image();
  lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
  lettreX.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreX, 40,149,95,107);

  }
}

function lettreO5()
{
  lettreO = new Image();
  lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
  lettreO.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreO, 145,149,110,107);

  }
}

function lettreX5()
{
  lettreX = new Image();
  lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
  lettreX.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreX, 145,149,110,107);

  }
}

function lettreO6()
{
  lettreO = new Image();
  lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
  lettreO.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreO, 265,149,95,107);
  }
}

function lettreX6()
{
  lettreX = new Image();
  lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
  lettreX.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreX, 265,149,95,107);

  }
}

function lettreO7()
{
  lettreO = new Image();
  lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
  lettreO.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreO, 40,40,95,101);
  }
}

function lettreX7()
{
  lettreX = new Image();
  lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
  lettreX.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreX, 40,40,95,101);

  }
}

function lettreO8()
{
  lettreO = new Image();
  lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
  lettreO.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreO, 145,40,110,101);

  }
}
function lettreX8()
{
  lettreX = new Image();
  lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
  lettreX.onload = function(){
context.drawImage(lettreX, 145,40,110,101);

  }
}
function lettreO9()
{
  lettreO = new Image();
  lettreO.src = 'O.jpg';
  lettreO.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreO, 265,40,95,101);
  }
}

function lettreX9()
{
  lettreX = new Image();
  lettreX.src = 'X.PNG';
  lettreX.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(lettreX, 265,40,95,101);
  }
}
```

Comment: you can create a model that represents the state of the tic tac toe, and when a spot is clicked review if your model has that specific spot filled, if so, then skip (return;)

Answer (score 0):

What I would normally do is have an array of values to store the moves already taken. For each move, I'd update it with whatever player put their mark in, then check for the default value before letting someone else place their symbol in that spot. FYI, arrays are zero based, so the first index is 0, not 1.

```
Moves = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
...
} else if (toucheCourante == Nombre9){
    if (Moves[8] == 0){
        Moves[8] = 2;
        lettreO9();
    }
}
```

There's quite a bit that could improve your code by learning about arrays.

```
NombresUp = [49, 50, 51, 52 ,53 ,54, 55, 56, 57];
Nombres = [97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105];
...
} else if (toucheCourante == Nombres[8]){ // this was Nombre9
```

There's also a lot that could be improved by passing parameters to your methods, too.

```
function lettre1(imageSource)
{
  var lettre = new Image();
  lettre.src = imageSource;
  lettre.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(lettre, 40, 265, 95, 93);
  }
}
...
lettre1('O.jpg');
// or 
lettre1('X.jpg');
```

Learning about objects would further clean up your code, but it seems like you already have a fair bit to learn and be comfortable with first, so I won't go into that. There's a lot of other improvements I could suggest, but I won't go into any of them either. I would basically be rewriting your game for you, so you probably wouldn't learn anything anyway. Since you are still learning, that's not a good way to teach you.

If you want to be real basic with this, put your global variable assignments (Nobmre1-9 & Nombreup1-9) in a method and call it for each game, then you can give them an invalid number when someone uses the spot. Since this is a ASCII number from the keyboard, you can make the invalid number -1.  This is not a good way to do it, but it would work.